# Why is my typeof check undefined failing my Mocha test?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai, karma-mocha

This code does not pass the test

**Functions:**

```
function setTheme(theme) {
    chartTheme = theme;
}

function getTheme() {
    if (typeof chartTheme === undefined) {
        chartTheme = 'dark';
    }
    return chartTheme;
}
```

**Test:**

```
it('If theme is undefined, expect dark', function() {
    ChartFactory.setTheme(undefined);
    expect(ChartFactory.getTheme()).to.equal('dark');
});
```

[image]

However this does past the test, if I check for `"undefined"` as a string.

```
function getTheme() {
    if (typeof chartTheme === 'undefined') {
        chartTheme = 'dark';
    }
    return chartTheme;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all see [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

You're using Strict equality operator with `undefined`. Strict equality check for both the type and value to be equal.

`typeof` returns **string**.

Thus,

```
typeof chartTheme === 'undefined'
```

returns `true`.

---

In other words,

```
undefined !== 'undefined'
```

but,

```
undefined == 'undefined'.
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I don't understand still is that `undefined` by itself is a type! Guess my code converted the `undefined` passed into the function to a string. Oh well I also just updated my code much more simply with these basic default checks: `theme = theme || 'dark';`

Comment: @LeonGaban Because the value of the variable is not actually defined. So, there should be some value which can tell this. Also, you can use ES6's default parameters as `function setTheme(theme = 'dark') {` instead of `|| 'dark'`.

Comment: Thanks on that ES6 tip! I just tried it tho, but got this error in the terminal `PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Expected token ')'` I guess I need some kind of Babel interpreter?

Comment: @LeonGaban probably. Most of the modern browsers support this syntax. See https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/